# How to fill the space of removed <div> by left or right positioned <div>?

Tags: css, html

I have 3 columns positioned beside each other.. one at left as the left modules panel, one at center as the content column, and one at right as the right modules panel.

CSS:

```css
#left{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#right{
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}

#content{
    width: 55%;
    float: right;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="right">
   some module
</div>
<div id="content">
   some content
</div>
<div id="left">
   some module
</div>
```

Now:
when i remove the div with id='left', the content div preserves its 55% position, and if i remove remove the 55%, it fills full width of the body. how can i set the content to fill the body from beside right panel till the left border of body when i remove the left panel?
for example, when i like to remove left panel from html code, i don't like to change contents 55% to 75%. i like it extend to all remaining 75% automatically.
i read similar questions but no success...

Comment: Can you please explain little more! It's confusing!

Comment: Better yet, a jsfiddle.net of this would be great (or even ascii art).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this solution, using `overflow:hidden`:

HTML

```html
<div id="right">
    some module
</div>
<div id="left">
    some module
</div>
<div id="content">
    some content
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#left{float:left; width:20%}
#right{float:right; width:25%}
#content{overflow:hidden;}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S4kNu/1/)

Take the left pane away and see what happens: the content will fill the remaining width.

I added some background colors, just to make it a little clearer.